# ¿porque htaccess funciona en una pagina pero en otra me da error 404?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hola actualmente estoy probando este codigo htaccess que permite ocultar las extensiones .php pero estoy teniendo errores ya que en una pagina funciona, pero en otra me tira errores 404 tratare de explicar lo mas detallado posible.
Entonces para comenzar tengo el siguiente htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ categoria.php?slug=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Al parecer todo funciona bien por que al ingresar en mipagina.com/categorias-blog entra perfectamente es decir quita la extension .php.
Ahora para las categorías vengo usando url con parametros el cual mando con GET desde el index uso lo siguiente

```
<a href="<?php echo $ruta_root . '/categoria/' . $namesCat ?>">
```

donde **$namesCa**t es el slug de la categoria. Para hacer las url amigables eh usado este pedazo de código en htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^categoria/(.*)$ categoria.php?slug=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

entonces basicamente me pasa de mipagina.com/categoria?slug=slug-de-la-categoria a mipagina.com/categoria/slug-de-la-categoria hasta ahi bien. Pero al intentar ingresar a esa pagina y usando el codigo htaccess para ocultar extension .php me tira error 404. En cambio si borro esto del htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

puedo ingresar a mipagina.com/categoria/slug-de-la-categoria y funciona pero al ingresar a  mipagina.com/categorias-blog me tira error 404 y solo puedo acceder a ella si coloco la extension mipagina.com/categorias-blog.php

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que cambiar el orden de las reglas

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ categoria.php?slug=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Ya que se va probando por orden y `^(.*)$` en `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php` "matchea" todo a `*.php`. Da error 404 porque está convirtiendo `categoria/slug-de-la-categoria` a `categoria/slug-de-la-categoria.php`